# Javascript GetDate in Options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm newbie with Javascript. I have that js code;

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    var options = {
        events_source: 'event.php',
        view: 'month',
        tmpl_path: 'tmpls/',
        tmpl_cache: false,
        day: '2022-12-31',
        onAfterEventsLoad: function(events) {
            if(!events) {
                return;
            }
            var list = $('#eventlist');
            list.html('');

            $.each(events, function(key, val) {
                $(document.createElement('li'))
                    .html('<a href="' + val.url + '">' + val.title + '</a>')
                    .appendTo(list);
            });
        },
```

I couldn't find how can i change "day: '2022-12-31'" to today date automaticly ? I tried some methods but didn't work.

Thanks for advice.

I tried let day = d.getDate();

Comment: _"I tried some methods but didn't work."_ - And those attempts have been...? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: *"I tried some methods but didn't work."* Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: i use 
let day = d.getDate();

then 

day: '2022-12-31', --> day: 'day()', 

sorry i'm newbie for js

Comment: Don't add relevant information (only) in a comment -> [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74969955/edit) your question and make it an actual [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code in your day property.

```
day: new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
```